# how to add Parent Element Name to Child Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

i have an input Element that Get Name of Helper but Two Element has same id 
 it is incorrect for Edit this problem,
 i want to Add Parent Div Id to Child Input.how can i Append ParentId to ChildId

```
 <div class="wrapper-merge-input">
            <div id="Stb" class="col-md-6   ">
                <label  class="control-label">StartDate</label>
                @page.Html.Raw(fromHtml)
            </div>
            <div id="Edb" class="col-md-6  ">
                <label class="control-label">EndDate</label>
                @page.Html.Raw(toHtml)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*And *

```
<input type="text" dir="ltr"   class="form-control"
   name="@name" id="@name"
   value="@value" 
   onclick="DatePicker.Show(this,'@today');" />
```

for example @name+Edb

Comment: you can use other attr like ref inspite of id that will not create error and you can given <input id="parentId"> and in child element <input ref ="parentId">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below shows how you can use `.attr("id")` to get an element's `id`. In order to travel up one level to the parent DOM element you should use `.parent()`.

You can also use `.attr("id", "new-id")` to set an attribute value. This can take strings or variables (as in the code below).

By placing the update code into a function you can call it on page load, after a click or any other event. I have made it run after a click of the button so you can see the `id` change.

I added some basic styling to make the demo a bit nicer to use.

Let me know if you wanted something else.

> **WARNING** you will likely want to make the `updateID()` function more specific, so it does not act on every input on the page.

```js
// Click event for button to demonstrate change
$("#startUpdate").click(function() {
  updateID();
});


function updateID() {

  // Cycle through each input - WARNING - you will want to make this more selective
  $("input").each(function() {

    // Update id of input from it's own name and it's immediate parent's id
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("name") + "-" + $(this).parent().attr("id"));

    // Print message to console to demonstrate id
    console.log("new id = " + $(this).attr("id"));

  });
}
```

```css
.wrapper-merge-input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#Edb {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#startUpdate {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-merge-input">
  <div id="Stb" class="col-md-6   ">
    <label class="control-label">StartDate</label>
    <input name="example1" id="example1" value="example1" onclick="DatePicker.Show(this,'@today');">
  </div>
  <div id="Edb" class="col-md-6  ">
    <label class="control-label">EndDate</label>
    <input name="example2" id="example2" value="example1" onclick="DatePicker.Show(this,'@today');">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="startUpdate">Update IDs</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear @Oliver Trampleasure it help me With a little Edition

Comment: Glad it helped!